# Golang Exec Command Long Output

Tags: go, ping

How can i get just a ping statistic from a very long ping command output:

```
func main() {
    cmdout, _ := exec.Command("ping", "127.0.0.1", "-n", "30000").Output()
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", cmdout)
}
```

I will need just this output:

```
Ping statistics for 127.0.0.1:
    Packets: Sent = 30000, Received = 30000, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

The output like:

```
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
...............................................
```

I just want to discard. I was thinking to get all this output into a variable and then parse it until i will get the needed result:

```
output := string(out)
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(strings.NewReader(output))
    for scanner.Scan() {
        fmt.Println("Line: ", scanner.Text())
        regex compile etc...
    }
```

But, I'm not sure that this is an efficient mode to achieve that, by choosing this way means to fill the RAM with a lot with unused data, which is not I'm looking at. I'm i right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following code is what i need:

```
func main() {
    args := "-n 30000 127.0.0.1"
    cmd := exec.Command("ping", strings.Split(args, " ")...)

    output, _ := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    cmd.Start()

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(output)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        m := scanner.Text()

        matchPackets, _ := regexp.MatchString("Packets", m)
        matchMinimum, _ := regexp.MatchString("Minimum", m)

        if matchPackets {
            fmt.Println("Ping statistics for 127.0.0.1")
            fmt.Println(m)
        }

        if matchMinimum {
            fmt.Println("Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:")
            fmt.Println(m)
        }
    }
    cmd.Wait()
}
```

Comment: You neglected to assign the write end of the pipe to Stdout, and even if did that the program would deadlock. The read end isn't closed until Wait is called, and Wait isn't called because the scanner never stops.